# Different toolbar icons depending on active tab

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

i am attempting to write a small email client with local storage for ubuntu touch.  I was wondering if there is a way for me to construct my toobar such that i only have to build one toolbar (rather than a different toolbar for each tab) and have it show different buttons depending on which tab is active, and how i would go about doing that (if it is possible).  This is because there are some toolbar buttons that will be static between the tabs (ie//delete, send to archive, forward or such) and some that will change based on the active tab...and i would rather not write a different toolbar for each tab.

ie//
something sort of like this:

if currentTab = 0
{ show static items and tab-dependent items }
       else if currentTab = 1
{ show static items and different tab-dependent items }

...and so on for each tab.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the parameter `visible` in `ToolbarButton`. For example:

```
ToolbarButton {
    visible: {
        if(currentTab == 0) return true
        else return false
    }
    action: Action {
        text: "Whatever"
        iconSource: Qt.resolvedUrl("images/icon.png")
        onTriggered: { print("Hello world") }
    }
}
```

This example will make it so this specific button is only visible when `currentTab` is equal to `0`, in other words, the first tab.